Duplicate node names
Although I am aware that node names have to be unique, I still would like to add a check and ensure that no two nodes with same name exist. Are there any ways to identify node from a unique id or anything similar apart from just node name? Or any other suggestions are also welcome.
I am using ros2-humble
Thanks in advance

have you tried to create nodes with duplicate names?

Yes, have two terminals and execute this command ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker in both terminals. In another terminal ros2 node list showed /talker /talker
